# Monkeypatching `__call__` on MagicMock

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest.mock, magicmock

Let's say I define a helper method to monkeypatch a simple modification into the `__call__` behavior of an existing object:

```
def and_print_on_call(instance):
  class AndPrintOnCall(type(instance)):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwarg):
      print('printed!')
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwarg)

  instance.__class__ = AndPrintOnCall
```

If I apply this to a typical class instance, it works as intended:

```
class Foo:
  def __call__(self):
    print('foo!')
foo = Foo()

and_print_on_call(foo)
foo()  # Prints "printed!" then "foo!"
```

But if I apply it to a `MagicMock` instance, it doesn't:

```
foo = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
foo.side_effect = lambda: print('foo!')

and_print_on_call(foo)
foo()  # Prints only "foo!"
```

Why? What is `MagicMock` doing special, that calling an instance of it apparently doesn't reference `__class__.__call__` like it would for a typical class?

---

To provide some broader context: I'm attempting to create a deep-copying mock, in order to handle mutable arguments (similar to what's discussed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#coping-with-mutable-arguments), though none of those provided solutions quite meet my particular needs). In the real implementation, the `print('printed!')` statement would instead be the copy logic.

Comment: https://github.com/wimglenn/copyingmock <-- FYI I've published a deep-copying mock already ([`pip install copyingmock`](https://pypi.org/project/copyingmock/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mocks intercept `__class__` assignment:](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L756)

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    ...
    elif name == '__class__':
        self._spec_class = value
        return
```

so your `instance.__class__ = AndPrintOnCall` doesn't actually work.